# Why does the logical or operator (||) with an empty arrow function (()=>{}) cause a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

In my code, I have something that boils down to this:

```
var x = y || ()=>{};
```

(In case you are wondering, I am later calling `x()` and `y` may be defined as a function or it might not, so I don't want a TypeError to be thrown if it is not.)

For some reason, this causes a

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Why? I found out that

```
var x = y || (()=>{});
```

works just fine, but

```
y || ()=>{}
```

dosen't work. Is this specced, or a bug in V8 or Chrome? (I tested this only in the latest release of Chrome stable.)

Comment: This is described [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order).  It's just the order of parsing.

Comment: Interestingly, this works with a regular function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is normal. Unlike a `function` expression, which is a [*PrimaryExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression) like other literals and identifiers, and arrow function specifically is an [*AssignmentExpression*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators) and can only appear inside grouping, comma, assignment, conditional (ternary) and yield expressions. Any other operator than those would lead to ambiguities.

For example, if you expect `y || ()=>z` to work, then also `()=>z || y` should be expected to work (assuming symmetric precedence). That however clearly collides with our expectation that we can use any operators inside concise bodies of arrow functions. Therefore, it's a syntax error and requires explicit grouping to work and stay maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug in the JavaScript engine.  This behavior is documented.

> Although the arrow in an arrow function is not an operator, arrow functions have special parsing rules that interact differently with operator precedence compared to regular functions.

<sub>Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order</sub>

Comment: What are those parsing rules?

Comment: It may be in the spec somewhere, I don't have time right now to search through it.  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/

Comment: Try to parse it with the [living spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262): if anything, then `x = y || () => {};` looks like an [_ExpressionStatement_](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionStatement). It doesn’t have any syntax at the start that prevents it from being in “expression context” (the “lookahead” part), so it’s an _Expression_ `;`; then _Expression → AssignmentExpression → LeftHandSideExpression_ `=` _AssignmentExpression_; the latter _AssignmentExpression_ now has a decision to make: is it (1) _AssignmentExpression → ArrowFunction_ or (2) _AssignmentExpression → ConditionalExpression_?

Comment: If (1), then it’s `x = ((y || ()) => {})`; if (2), then `x = (y) || (() => {})`. But in case of (1), _ArrowFunction → ArrowParameters_ `=>` _ConciseBody_; _ArrowParameters_ is `y || ()`, which is not a _BindingIdentifier_. It’s also not a _CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList_ (_CPE&APL_ for short) because it lacks surrounding parentheses. There are no alternatives in (1). If we follow (2), then _ConditionalExpression → ShortCircuitExpression → LogicalORExpression_ (_CoalesceExpression_ does not fit) → _LogicalORExpression_ `||` _LogicalANDExpression_.

Comment: That means `y || () => {}` would need to fit _LogicalORExpression_ `||` _LogicalANDExpression_. `y` is a valid _LogicalORExpression_, but _LogicalANDExpression → BitwiseORExpression → BitwiseXORExpression → BitwiseANDExpression → EqualityExpression → RelationalExpression → ShiftExpression → AdditiveExpression → MultiplicativeExpression → ExponentiationExpression → UnaryExpression → UpdateExpression → LeftHandSideExpression_. Now, there are three options, but the closest that fits is _LeftHandSideExpression → NewExpression → MemberExpression → PrimaryExpression_.

Comment: Here, nothing will bring us back to _Expression → AssignmentExpression → ArrowFunction_; the closest candidate would again be _CPE&APL_, but `() => {}` is still not surrounded with parentheses. There is no alternative and there is no other option. This cannot be parsed, and therefore is invalid syntax. The non-terminal _CPE&APL_ looks like the “special parsing rules” that prevents this syntax. And the _why_ has been explained in the other answers.

Answer (score -4):

try this `var x =( y || (()=>{}));`