# What is the exact parsing precedence of arrow function (fat arrow =>) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I came across an example from [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-confusing-arrow) on arrow function:

```js
// The intent is not clear
var x = a => 1 ? 2 : 3;
```

So I researched a bit regarding the precedence of arrow functions. It seems that `=>` is not considered an operator, as it cannot be found on the [table of operator precedence on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table). And from the page [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order), it says that

> arrow functions have special parsing rules that interact differently with operator precedence compared to regular functions.

But it does not further elaborate on the *special parsing rules*. So my question is, **what is the rule of precedence regarding arrow functions?**

---

Based on my test, it seems that its precedence is higher than an assignment, but lower than the conditional(ternary) operator?

```js
var x = 0, a = 5;
console.log(x = a => 1 ? 2 : 3);
// same as x = (a => (1 ? 2 : 3))
console.log(x);
console.log(a);
```

But I'm not sure if this is consistent on different browsers and platforms. Can anyone give a definitive answer to this behavior?

Comment: *"But I'm not sure if this is consistent on different browsers and platforms."* Yes, it is. JavaScript is precisely specified in [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/). Largely, the era of different JavaScript engines implementing specified behavior differently ended with IE11. *New* features that aren't finished yet may vary, but by the time they're in the spec, they're consistent.

Comment: fat `arrow` syntax is not  an "operator"... just syntax denoting an arrow function.

Comment: Am I the only one that couldn't understand the question?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I'm asking _how does JS parser handle `=>` mixed with operators_, if this sounds clearer to you.

Comment: Actually the arrow function is now on the [table of operator precedence on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you say, `=>` is not an operator. Arrow functions are primary syntax.

The rules for them are defined in the specification, starting with the [*ArrowFunction* production](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-asi-rules-ArrowFunction). *ArrowFunction* is defined as *ArrowParameters* followed by `=>` followed by the misleadingly-named [*ConciseBody*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ConciseBody). *ConciseBody* has two forms. You're asking about the form using [*ExpressionBody*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionBody), which is where the first non-whitespace token after `=>` *isn't* `{`. If there were an opening curly brace there it would denote the opening of a block called a *FunctionBody* instead.

The [*ExpressionBody*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionBody) definition is quite simple: it's an [*AssignmentExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-AssignmentExpression).

Which takes us into very familiar territory, because *AssignmentExpression* is the syntax for the right-hand side of an assignment (or variable initializer), entries in an array initializer, the value part of a property initializer, an argument to a function, etc. So whatever follows the `=>` in a concise body has the same parsing rules as what we put where AssignmentExpression is below:

```
x = AssignmentExpression;
y = AssignmentExpression, z = AssignmentExpression;
a1 = [AssignmentExpression];
a2 = [AssignmentExpression, AssignmentExpression];
o1 = {foo: AssignmentExpression};
o2 = {foo: AssignmentExpression, bar: AssignmentExpression};
doSomething(AssignmentExpression);
doSomething(AssignmentExpression, AssignmentExpression);
```

Just for detail, an *AssignmentExpression* is any of:

- [*ConditionalExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ConditionalExpression) (as in your example)
- [*YieldExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-YieldExpression)
- [*ArrowFunction*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ArrowFunction)
- [*AsyncArrowFunction*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-AsyncArrowFunction)
- [*LeftHandSideExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression) = *AssignmentExpression*
- [*LeftHandSideExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression) [*AssignmentOperator*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-AssignmentOperator) *AssignmentExpression*

---

(You may wonder, [as I did](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/embarrassingly-simple-spec-question), how the `y` in `x = y` can match *AssignmentExpression* given the definition of it above, since `y` is clearly an [*Identifier*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-Identifier) and none of those looks like it will lead to the *Identifier* production. This is where specs can be really hard to read. It turns out that you get there if you keep going long enough. The path is (deep breath): [*AssignmentExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-AssignmentExpression) →
[*ConditionalExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ConditionalExpression) →
[*LogicalORExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-LogicalORExpression) →
[*LogicalANDExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-LogicalANDExpression) →
[*BitwiseORExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-BitwiseORExpression) →
[*BitwiseXORExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-BitwiseXORExpression) →
[*BitwiseANDExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-BitwiseANDExpression) →
[*EqualityExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-EqualityExpression) →
[*RelationalExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-RelationalExpression) →
[*ShiftExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ShiftExpression) →
[*AdditiveExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-AdditiveExpression) →
[*MultiplicativeExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-MultiplicativeExpression) →
[*ExponentiationExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-ExponentiationExpression) →
[*UnaryExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-UnaryExpression) →
[*UpdateExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-UpdateExpression) →
[*LeftHandSideExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression) →
[*NewExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-NewExpression) →
[*MemberExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-MemberExpression) →
[*PrimaryExpression*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-PrimaryExpression) →
[*IdentifierReference*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-IdentifierReference) →
[*Identifier*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-Identifier) — whew! *[mops brow]*. Thank you Oriol!)

Comment: Now, I understood the question. :)

Comment: In another word, on the parser level, `=>` is of the exact same precedence as an assignment operator, with RTL associativity, correct?

Comment: @zypA13510 - Primary syntax doesn't have precedence or associativity. It's just how the syntax works as you follow the parser. But I think you could think of it that way, yes. The example above I find particularly helpful in understanding concise bodies is the `y = AssignmentExpression, z = AssignmentExpression;` one, because I'm very familiar with how that's parsed, and so I can extend it to arrow functions fairly easily. For instance, using that as my reference point, I know that `result = array.reduce((a, v) => a * v, 1)` is parsed *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* as `result = array.reduce(((a, v) => a * v), 1)`, not `result = array.reduce((a, v) => (a * v, 1))`. But I also know that `x = a => 1 ? 2 : 3` is parsed as `x = a => (1 ? 2 : 3)` not `x = (a => 1) ? 2 : 3`, just from long familiarity. But just like with long strings of nested conditionals, everyone struggles with arrows sometimes. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But if `=>` is a _primary syntax_ that does not have precedence (or associativity), wouldn't it be confusing because `callback = callback || () => {};` throws a SyntaxError? In compiled languages, this would probably be handled by the compiler. Instead, it throws a SyntaxError. So my understanding is, there is some precedence rule working here, isn't it?

Comment: @zypA13510 - There's no *parsing* difference between a "compiled language" and any other kind of language (and JavaScript is often compiled -- in V8, it was *always* compiled until recently). Even with an interpreter, the first step is parsing. AFAIK, "precedence" and "associativity" are just meta concepts we use to help us understand how operators are defined to work; you won't find either word in the spec. It all comes down to the defined syntax and semantics of the language. JavaScript has a **very** complex syntax as a result of having "grown" over a period of 20 years.

Comment: @zypA13510 - I'm afraid that I'm not good enough with the notation used by the spec to tell you why `callback = callback || () => {};` doesn't work. (I have tried. The notation used is -- for me -- extremely hard to understand.) If fact, answering your question inspired me to write my own [question about the notation](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/embarrassingly-simple-spec-question) on the es-discuss mailing list. :-) Presumably it's reading that first `(` as the grouping operator, but I can't tell you why. :-( It's in there somewhere.

Comment: A question today made it clear that in the grammar, *all* `=>` function bodies are *ConciseBody* non-terminals. A *ConciseBody* is either an *AssignmentExpression* or a (traditional) *FunctionBody*.

Comment: In ES2019 _AssignmentExpression_ has been renamed in the relevant section of the spec, to _ExpressionBody_. https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-ExpressionBody

Comment: @Ben - Thanks. Looks like my initial answer was slightly incorrect as well, the spec uses *ConciseBody* for any kind of body on an arrow function (even a verbose one), and as far as I can tell always has. Oops to me for misreading it, and oops to them for misnaming it. :-D

Comment: Interestingly MDN have now added the arrow to their [operator precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table) so I guess they now consider it an operator.

Comment: @Nick - See Note #1 on that page: *"Not all syntax included here are "operators" in the strict sense. For example, spread ... and arrow => are typically not regarded as operators."* Neither `...` nor `=>` is an operator (there's no "regarded" about it :-) ), but apparently they thought it would help to show how they get handled relative to operators.

Comment: I should read more closely :(, still interesting to see that they do now define where it sits in precedence to operators

Comment: @Nick - It is indeed, thanks for pointing it out. And I can see why. You look at `x = () => y && z` and think, "now is that `&& z` inside the function or not?" :-D

Comment: Something similar to that just came up in another question, which is how I ended up here. I posted a comment to the question, so hopefully anyone else coming here will see that.

Answer (score 7):

> It does not further elaborate on the special parsing rules.

They're not that *special*, they're just different. A `function` expression is a so-called primary expression that can occur anywhere in code. It's very clear from its syntactical form `function …(…) {…}` what elements it consists of, explicitly delimiting start and end.

In contrast, an arrow function can have an expression body without using a block, so it is not delimited explicitly. We therefore need restrictions on what things can appear inside the body of an arrow function and what things can not, to resolve ambiguity in a sequence of tokens containing a `=>`.

> So my question is, what is the rule of precedence regarding arrow functions?

Basically, `=>` has the same "precedence" as the `=` assignment operator.
(We just don't like to call `=>` an operator, as it constructs a value instead of computing a result after evaluating its operands)

This means that we can put an arrow function in any place where an assignment could occur:

- as element values in array or object literals
- as default initialisers (destructuring, function parameters)
- as variable initialisers
- as expression statements or in loop headers
- as function arguments
- as grouped expressions

Those are all unambiguous. The ambiguous cases are more interesting:

- at the right hand side of an assignment
- at the right hand side of the conditional operator
- at the right hand side of the `yield` operator
- at any side of the comma operator

Having to put an arrow function in a place where an assignment would be valid also means that we **cannot** put it (directly, without grouping) as an operand of any other (higher-precedence) operator - most notably [not as an operand of logical expressions (`||`, `&&`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42679078/1048572).

The body of the arrow function can be an assignment expression (including anything of higher precedence) again, so the `=>` is right-associative (just like `=`). The body will be parsed greedily (the expression is made as long as possible) so that it will contain basically all expressions on the right hand side of the `=>`.

The only things that cannot form an arrow function's concise body are a `yield` expression (not allowed outside generator functions anyway) and a comma expression.

Comment: This answer needs updating in light of new information coming to light about nomenclature surrounding `ConciseBody` and `FunctionBody`.

Comment: @Ben I thought it did not since I haven't referred to those nonterminals, but you're right I've clarified