# Javascript OR (II) variable assignment to arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to assign an arrow function to a variable in OR (`||`) assignment, without creating new var.

It works, when I assign regular function, or variable with arrow function, but I cannot assign an arrow function inline

This doesn't work:

```
const onClick = onClick || (e) => e
```

This works:

```
const func = (e) => e
const onClick = onClick || func
const onClick = onClick || function(e) {return e}
```

Comment: `const onClick = onClick || (e) => e` what do you intend the second `onClick` to refer to? This is the very same line you're defining what onClick is.

Comment: You are using the same name of Left and Right Hand side.

Comment: `const onClick = onClick || ((e) => e);` ? Note also that `(e) => e` can be abbreviated to `e => e`

Comment: A declaration like `const`, `let`, or `var` always creates a new variable.

Comment: Yes, I want to check if onClick exists, and if not, assign the function on the right side

Comment: If `onClick` exists then you can't redeclare it.

Comment: @str Yes it is a duplicate, couldn't find this question earlier. Can you please mark as duplicate?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679078/why-does-the-logical-or-operator-with-an-empty-arrow-function-caus and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461820/what-is-the-exact-parsing-precedence-of-arrow-function-fat-arrow-in-javascr