# Immediately executed anonymous function syntax ambiguity

Tags: javascript

Why is the following a syntax error?

```
(()=>{console.log(1)}())
```

`()=>{console.log(1)}` is clearly(?) an expression that evaluates to a fat arrow function, and `()` "should" call it?

Presumably because it is ambiguous. What is the ambiguity?

Obviously, I realise the following works:

```
(()=>{console.log(1)})()
```

Comment: Because your left () is empty.

Comment: @SPlatten no, this is not the issue.

Comment: I really don't understand why people are downvoting this question. This is a legit question about JS parsing...

Comment: `(()=>{})()` is a shorthand for `IIFE` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: @DenisTsoi OP's question is why does it need to be enclosed in parenthesis to be called ?

Comment: @Seblor Possible reason for downvotes: the title of the question might be baiting people into thinking the question is lower quality than it really is. It doesn't really reflect what you're asking, and sounds like someone asking how to write IIFEs without looking it up first.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but finding the answer imho looks pretty straight forward: open the spec, go to the related grammar rules, find out, why the parser is including the bracket after the closing curly into the token. Almost surely some ambiguity with a different syntax feature.

Comment: the pattern is such that, for the anonymous function declaration defined -> `(() => {})` should be immediately called with the following `()`

another example could be `((item) => { // do something with item })(1)`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461820/what-is-the-exact-parsing-precedence-of-arrow-function-fat-arrow-in-javascr

Comment: @ASDFGerte I'd argue that finding something specific without knowing where is should be defined in the spec can be a bit of a hassle

Comment: @Seblor hence why i didn't downvote it.

Comment: Neither of the "duplicates" answer this question as far as I can see.

Comment: The duplicates state "this is how you do it", not "this is why the language semantics require this"

Comment: @ASDFGerte I'm not sure the spec will actually point out the ambiguity. It will merely define the grammar?

Comment: My best guess is because there is nothing in the language grammar that defines an "arrow function _expression_". The static semantic [`IsFunctionDefinition`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-isfunctiondefinition) for `AssignmentExpression` always evaluates to `true` for `ArrowFunction` and `AsyncArrowFunction`, and a function definition is not callable.

Comment: I was mostly commenting to "why is this getting downvoted". The issue is, that after knowing the immediate solution (put extra brackets), a question of "give me the parser details" imho raises the bar for own effort. As mentioned multiple times, i didn't downvote here, but i would have been much happier, if the question included attempts to read the related grammar, and find out, why this is happening, and where you got stuck there. I mean, that's what i am doing right now, reading the spec, searching for why it parses this way (cause curiosity killed the cat, you know :) )

Comment: About the spec, yes, it likely will not have a "Note: you need to put extra brackets around arrow function IIFE because ...", but ambiguities in parsing a certain sequence are often obvious, when knowing every grammar rule related.

Comment: This is just a complex version of JFGI?

Comment: "*What is the ambiguity?*" - it is when the arrow function does not have a block body but a concise body. [That's why you cannot use arrow functions as operands to many operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461820/what-is-the-exact-parsing-precedence-of-arrow-function-fat-arrow)

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around it. Don't currently understand how a block can be ambiguous with a concise body.

Comment: So are you saying that `() => { console.log('') }` is never implicitly expressionized, and is always an arrow function declaration? If those words make sense.

Comment: @Ben In short, `a = b = () => a = b = c` is valid and has resolved ambiguity through precedence rules. `a = () => b () () ()` is the same  - and equal to `a = () => { return b()()(); }`, not to `a = (() => b)()()()`. This is why `() => { b() }` is not allowed in that position either, even if an arrow function with a block body wouldn't be ambiguous.

Comment: @Ben Yes, it's always parsed as an arrow function expression, with the same grammar rules as a concise-body one.

Comment: @Ben that's what _I_ was saying. I'm not quite sure if that's what Bergi was getting at, but his comment is definitely related. His focused on what ambiguity in the grammar is being avoided by not "expressionizing" it, while mine focused on where it shows it is never "expressionized". **edit** well, _now_ he's said it.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts "*there is nothing in the language grammar that defines an "arrow function expression"*" - yes there is (although it might be hidden behind one of these ugly "cover grammar" things). The parse error has nothing to do with the arrow function being parsed as a declaration (those don't exist, it's always an expression). But yes, it's an `AssignmentExpression`, and they cannot appear inside a call expression.

Comment: @Bergi nit: `/expression/definition`. ECMAScript never mentions an "arrow function expression". I realize I'm being pedantic, but there is an `ArrowFunction` expression, which is a valid grammar for an `AssignmentExpression`, but the respective section in ECMAScript uses the phrase "Arrow function definition" for defining the grammar of `ArrowFunction`.

Comment: Sorry, I keep writing "declaration" where I mean to write "definition"...

Comment: OK, so I now loosely understand the proximate grammar reasons, but I don't understand the "ultimate why". Is it to do with the order of lexing? `()=>{}` is famously ambiguous, but to a human `()=>{console.log('')}` is unambiguous. As we saying that the latter is also ambiguous to the parser?

Comment: @Ben the ambiguity you're referring to is unrelated. It's solved by the grammar [`CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#prod-CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList). Re-read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60042743/immediately-executed-anonymous-function-syntax-ambiguity#comment106190409_60042743) a few times and let it sink in. The ambiguity being solved is `() => b()` vs. `(() => b)()`, not `() => { b }` vs `() => ({ b })`

Comment: How do you link to a comment BTW?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment

Comment: Unsure whether to post this here, or on your new (probably related) question. I am also still not exactly sure about the "why". It looks like CallExpression cannot have an arrow function, unless it's parenthesized. In other words, the chain CallExpression-PrimaryExpression-FunctionExpression exists, but for arrow functions, there is only the path over expressions in parenthesis. Don't see yet, why ConciseBody productions can't get their own names, and CallExpression-PrimaryExpression-ArrowFunctionWithBody (some new name) added. Still searching ~~~

Comment: Can we get some reopen votes on this q please?

Comment: @Ben tbh I would've marked it as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50461820/1048572 if it wasn't already closed

Comment: It not a dupe of that because that q asks "what", this asks "why".

Comment: My current interpretation of the question is: "Couldn't the grammar be changed, so arrow-functions with {FunctionBody} (not the ones with ExpressionBody) are added to the PrimaryExpression production (like function-expressions), without causing damage elsewhere?". I originally guessed, that it wasn't possible, because this would cause some unsolvable ambiguity. However, i now feel more and more, like it may have other reasons, perhaps even arbitrary ones (e.g. making the grammar/parsing unnecessarily more complex, or even just not having been considered yet, due to being unimportant).