# Why is the arrow function ()=>{} invalid syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm reading the [parsing order section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#parsing_order) of Mozilla's doc about arrow functions and I wonder why () => {} throws an error. I thought it was a valid syntax for when there are no parameters. How is () => {} different from (() => {}) ?

```
let callback;

callback = callback || function() {}; // ok

callback = callback || () => {};
// SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments

callback = callback || (() => {});    // ok
```

Comment: Presumably the parentheses cause the arrow function to be evaluated *first.*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Most likely, the problem is that `callback = callback || (arg) => {}` is ambiguous. Is it `(callback = callback || (arg)) => {}` or is it `callback = callback || ((arg) => {})`? The ECMAScript grammar resolves this ambiguity by requiring explicit grouping.

Comment: Re: @Odinh's link, see [this specific paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#parsing_order)

Comment: @Brian: [Your link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#parsing_order) is where the OP took their example in the question from. It doesn't really explain *why* this is a problem, just "arrow functions have special parsing rules that interact differently with operator precedence compared to regular functions", and that example code, which shows *what* doesn't work without being clear on the *why*.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does the logical or operator (||) with an empty arrow function (()=>{}) cause a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42679078/4642212). See also [What is the exact parsing precedence of arrow function (fat arrow =>) in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50461820/4642212) (make sure to find citations to the [up-to-date specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)).

Comment: @ShadowRanger exactly, I couldn't find the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's what I suspected, which is why I thought it was relevant context for the question. Since the OP confirmed that that was the source, I went ahead and linked it directly in the question.

Comment: @SebastianSimon you're right! Thanks everyone!