# Getting "Unexpected token" error for an inline arrow function in create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint, create-react-app

When I try to run the following code:

```
const handleClick = onClick || () => push(route);
```

I get a compilation error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token
```

But when I run:

```
const test = () => push(route);
const handleClick = onClick || test;
```

It works just fine.

Surely `const handleClick = onClick || () => push(route);` is valid syntax, why am I getting this error?

My relevant `dependencies` are:

```
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
```

And my `.eslintrc.js` file is simply:

```
module.exports = {
  env: { node: true, es2020: true, jest: true },
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:prettier/recommended', 'react-app']
```

Comment: `const handleClick = onClick || (() => push(route));`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the logical or operator (||) with an empty arrow function (()=>{}) cause a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679078/why-does-the-logical-or-operator-with-an-empty-arrow-function-caus)

Comment: @jonrsharpe link should give an answer to your query