# Assigning arrow function as the default value with ||

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, function-expression

So I was writing a function which would take an argument(another function), which when undefined would be assigned a default value. Assigning that default value as an `()=>{}` does not seem to work.
However when I wrap the default function in `(()=>{})` or write a normal `function()`, it seems to work just fine.
Something like this code below:

---

### Not Working

```js
const f1 = f2 => {
  f2 = f2 || () => alert("No default Listeners defined!");
}
```

### Working

```js
const f1 = f2 => {
  f2 = f2 || (() => alert("No default Listeners defined!"));
}

const f3 = f2 => {
  f2 = f2 || function() {
    alert("No default Listeners defined!")
  };
}
```

---

Can I please get an explanation as to why the first one is not working and the next 2 are working? I suspect it might be related to ***function-declaration*** *V*  ***function-expression*** and I searched a bit for this but could not find a proper explanation. A link with the same would also suffice. Thank you.

Comment: worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461820/what-is-the-exact-parsing-precedence-of-arrow-function-fat-arrow-in-javascr maybe dupe ...?

Comment: It's being parsed as if you'd written `f2 = (f2 || ()) => alert("No default Listeners defined!");`

Comment: That should be obvious: `f2 || ()` is considered as an arguments list for `=>` (arrow function definition), that's why you got this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use arrow function with || operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795104/how-to-use-arrow-function-with-operator/39795159#39795159).

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks guys. So should I go ahead and delete the question or just let it stay? Help me out here

Comment: `f2 = f2 || _ => alert` might work too